# Extract attribute value of a hidden input element using DOMXPath

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

I have a got piece of HTML code:

```
<form method="post" action="/">
  <input type="hidden" name="example-name" value="example-value">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How can I extract value of the hidden input using DOMXPath in PHP?
I have tried somethig like this:

```
//$site - the html code
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($site);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$kod = $xpath->query("//input[@name='example-name']");
foreach($kod as $node)
$values[]=$node->nodeValue;
return $values;
```

But it returns an empty array. Where is the mistake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this to get the `value` attribute of the `input` element with the `name` attribute *example-name*

```
'//input[@name="example-name"]/@value'
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => example-value
)
```

Your XPath didn't select the attribute axis (*I think that's what it's called*) but the text axis and since input has no text, the value in the array was empty. It did find the element though.

Answer (score 4):

```
$node->getAttribute('value');
```