# PHP parse HTML empty input value

Tags: php, html, xml, xpath

I know there are many questions on parsing HTML in PHP, but I can't seem to find the specific problem I'm experiencing. My code works on other elements in the page, and also iterates over the inputs returning the tag name. At the same time their value property is empty, when 2 of them have a value for sure. Here is my code

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://...sample website...html');
$doc = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*/input[@type='hidden']");
if(!is_null($elements)){
    foreach ($elements as $element) {
      echo "<br/>[". $element->nodeName. "]";
      echo $element->nodeValue. "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xpath->query("//*/input[@type='hidden']/@value");
```

instead of

```
$xpath->query("//*/input[@type='hidden']");
```

also works well.

[Same question, same answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214811/extract-attribute-value-of-a-hidden-input-element-using-domxpath)

Answer (score 0):

I got it myself, if anyone else has a similar problem it is just that nodeValue returns the "innerHTML" of an element, to get its properties use `$element -> getAttribute("value")` (for the "value" attribute)